# Does this solve boolean satisfiability problem in polynomial time?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra, np-complete, satisfiability, conjunctive-normal-form

CNF can be easily converted into a formula that uses only `AND` and `NOT` operations, using the fact that `a OR b = NOT(NOT(a) AND NOT(b))`, in linear time.

This formula can be represented as a graph, where an edge goes down to `T` or `F` depending on whether that variable or intermediate node is `AND`ed without or with `NOT`:
[image: AND-NOT Graph]
This problem can be further reduced to [Horn satisfiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability) as the picture above shows, by using the fact that `(x=>y) = NOT(x) OR y` and introducing substitution variables so to satisfy the requirement for all clauses to be [Horn clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause). In turn, Horn satisfiability can be solved in linear time.

So it seems that boolean satisfiability can be solved in linear time with this approach.

Comment: Not all logic expressions can be captured by Horn Clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea of reducing a more-or-less arbitrary expression to Horn clauses (without incurring exponential blowup) is highly suspect, since it turns a hard problem into a super-easy one.  Indeed, I think you have miscalculated the effect of introducing the conditions $(\bar{a} \vee x_2)(a \vee \bar{x_2})$: this actually forces $a = x_2$, not $a = \bar{x_2}$.  It makes sense that Horn clauses would not be able to express negation very well, since they express a certain type of monotonicity.